# Why is Selenium C# Chrome not storing Session Data to user-data-dir?

Tags: c#, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, whatsapp

Im trying to automate WhatsApp Web, for that i want to save the session data in order not to need to scan the QR Code every time. I do that adding the user-data-dir argument:
`options.AddArgument("--user-data-dir=userdata");`

Chrome stores the data to this folder, but it seems like it only does that on startup. When i quit the Driver with `driver.Close();` or `driver.Quit();` the data is probably not being stored, because the driver 'kills' Chrome. **When i start Chrome without headless and close the window using the close button the data is stored and loaded on the next startup.**

Is there any way or workaround to manually store the session data or to gracefully close Chrome?

One workaround that i dont like is, that the user needs to manually close the window on the first time to store the user data.
Would be happy to see your suggestions

Comment: Also i just noticed that when i start Chome without headless i get "Google Chrome didn't shut down correctly. To reopen the pages you had open, click Restore."